# Powershell For Loop In Reverse

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
$testString = "abcdef"
for ($ia=$testString.length-1; $ia -gt 0; $ia - 2) {
$testString[$ia]
}
```

I need output "fedcba"
But keep getting "fffffffffff..."

How can I reverse the testString output by each character in this for loop format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using `$ia - 2` ?

You need to change that to `$ia--` so it decrements one at a time.

Also change `$ia -gt 0` to `$ia -ge 0` so it reaches the last index.

Comment: Not sure how it was changed to $ia - 2 , I had it as - 1. But thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 4):

Another way with a reverse range in the array index.  It should really start at length-1, but it's easier this way and it works.  I wish I could do [-1..0] ([-1..-100]?).

```
$teststring = 'abcdef'
$teststring[$teststring.length..0]

f
e
d
c
b
a


-join $teststring[$teststring.length..0]

fedcba


-join $teststring[-1..-$teststring.length]

fedcba
```

Comment: Genius solution. I needed something that supported complex objects.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it.

```
$testString = "abcdef"
for ($ia=$testString.length-1; $ia -ge 0; $ia--) {
$testString[$ia]
}
```

You can use `$ia--` to decrement down and you should get your result. Also, you should use `-ge` for greater than or equal to 0 as you want to capture `index 0` of the array.

Also, vice versa, you can do the following:

```
$testString = "abcdef"
for ($ia=$testString.length; $ia -gt -1; $ia--) {
$testString[$ia]
}
```

Both works, but I prefer the second one as it's easier to read.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to make you aware that there is also a static dotnet [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.array.reverse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Reverse_System_Array_) method from the [`[Array]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8) class:

```
$CharArray = $teststring.ToCharArray()
[Array]::Reverse($CharArray)
$CharArray
f
e
d
c
b
a
```

Related GitHub purpose: [`#16644` Add -Reverse parameter to Sort-Object](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16644)